# Add System.Text.Json to incremental source generator

Tags: c#, json, roslyn, system.text.json, sourcegenerators

My source generator has a dependency on `System.Text.Json`, but I get the following error message:

> Generator 'Generator' failed to generate source. It will not contribute to the output and compilation errors may occur as a result. Exception was of type 'TypeInitializationException' with message 'The type initializer for 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer' threw an exception.'. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer' threw an exception.
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Project link: https://github.com/JanTamis/OpenAPIGenerator

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#use-functionality-from-nuget-packages

Comment: ive tried to use this method but it still doesn't work

Comment: If you look in the NuGet package (you can just look inside if you rename the extension to .zip) did the binary appear there? You also may have to look at a log of the MSBuild invocation to confirm it's also being passed to the compiler in the regular build.